# React Native 'TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'navigation.navigate')'

Tags: react-native

This is my first React Native project and I am stuck and need help. Following is my code. What I am trying to do is following.

1. Landing screen will have list of all projects and bottom tab menu.
2. Once someone clicks on project, it will open project details page.

App.Js

```js
/**
 * Sample React Native App
 * https://github.com/facebook/react-native
 *
 * @format
 * @flow strict-local
 */
import React from 'react';
import App from './src';
import { Provider as PaperProvider } from 'react-native-paper';

export default App;
```

src/navigations/index.js

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, FlatList, SafeAreaView } from 'react-native';
import { List, Button, TextInput, FAB, Avatar, Card, Title, Paragraph } from 'react-native-paper';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import { createStackNavigator} from '@react-navigation/stack';
import ProjectList from '_scenes/projects';
import NewProject from '_scenes/projects/addproject';
import ProjectDetail from '_scenes/projects/projectdetails';
import Settings from '_scenes/settings';


const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();


const Projects = ({ navigation }) => (
    <ProjectList navigation={navigation} />
);


function SettingsScreen( { navigation} ) {
  return (
    <Settings />
  );
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Tab.Navigator initialRouteName="HomeScreen">
        <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={Projects} options={{ tabBarBadge: 3 }}/>
        <Tab.Screen name="Settings" component={SettingsScreen} options={{ tabBarBadge: 2 }}/>
      </Tab.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

src/scenes/projects/index.js

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { ActivityIndicator, FlatList, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { Item, List, Button } from 'react-native-paper';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import { createStackNavigator} from '@react-navigation/stack';
import NewProject from '_scenes/projects/addproject';
import ProjectDetail from './projectdetails';

ProjectList = ({ navisation }) => {

  const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/projects')
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((json) => setData(json))
      .catch((error) => console.error(error))
      .finally(() => setLoading(false));
  }, []);

  function Projects ( {navigation }) {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, padding: 24 }}>
        <FlatList
        data={data} 
        keyExtractor={({ id }, index) => id}
        renderItem={renderProject}
        />
      </View>
    )
    }

  const renderProject = ({ navigation, item }) => (
    <List.Item
    title={item.title}
    description={item.description}
    onPress={() => navigation.navigate('ProjectDetails')}
    />
  );

  const AddProject = ({ navigation }) => (
      <NewProject />
  );

  function ProjectDetails({navigation}) {
    return (
      <ProjectDetail />
    );
  }

  function Chat({navigation}) {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>Chat</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }



  const Stack = createStackNavigator();
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen title="Home" name="Home" component={Projects} options={{headerShown: false}}/>
      <Stack.Screen title="Add Project" name="AddProject" component={AddProject} />
      <Stack.Screen title="Project Details" name="ProjectDetails" component={ProjectDetails} />
      <Stack.Screen title="Chat" name="Chat" component={Chat} />      
    </Stack.Navigator>

    );
};

export default ProjectList;
```

if you see "`renderProject`" I want to navigate to "`ProjectDetails`" when clicked. but I receive error  `'TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'navigation.navigate')'` let me know what is wrong?

Comment: You have a typo `navisation` in the `ProjectList` props.  You should not define components inside of other components.  Move them to the top-level of your file.

Comment: Thank you @LindaPaiste I rectified the typo, but still I see same error. I will read about the second part and see if I understand what you explained, please share links if you have them handy.